# ¿Por qué me muestra así mi pdf?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

[image]

Tengo un sistema web hecho en php a en el cual una de las funciones es visualizar archivos pdf en el navegador, sin embargo a la hora de abrir el pdf me aparece lo de la imagen y, no me muestra el archivo.

Este es mi código para visualizar mi pdf, espero puedan ayudarme

```
    <?php
   include "c.php";
    $db=new Conect_MySql();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_archivos where id_archivos=".$_GET['id'];
        $query = $db->execute($sql);
        if($datos=$db->fetch_row($query)){
            if($datos['ruta']==""){?>
    <p>NO tiene archivos</p>
            <?php }else{ 
              header('content-type: application/pdf');
              readfile('upload/'.$datos['ruta']);
             } } ?>
```

Esto es lo que hay en c.php, es mi conexión a la base de datos, de hecho menciono que esta conexión a la base de datos unicamente la ocupo para el visualizador, en localhost me funciona a la perfección el problema es ya arriba en el host

```
         <?php 
         class Conect_MySql {   
          var $obj = array ( "dbname"   =>  "***",
                   "dbuser"     =>  "****"      ,
                   "dbpwd"      =>  "***"       ,
                   "dbhost"     =>  "****"  );
         var $q_id  ="";
          var $ExeBit   ="";
          var $db_connect_id = "";
          var $query_count   = 0;
          private function connect(){
          $this->db_connect_id = mysqli_connect($this->obj['dbhost'],$this- 
           >obj['dbuser'],$this->obj['dbpwd'],$this->obj['dbname']);
          if (!$this->db_connect_id)
           {
             echo (" Error no se puede conectar al 
           servidor:".mysqli_connect_error());
          }
           }
         function execute($query) {       
       $this->q_id = mysqli_query($this->db_connect_id,$query);        
           if(!$this->q_id ) {
         $error1 = mysqli_error($this->db_connect_id);
         die ("ERROR: error DB.<br> No Se Puede Ejecutar La Consulta:<br> 
            $query <br>MySql Tipo De Error: $error1");
          exit;
             }         
         $this->query_count++; 
             return $this->q_id;    
          }
          public function fetch_row($q_id = "") {
         if ($q_id == "") {
          $q_id = $this->q_id;
          }
           $result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_id);
          return $result;
           }    
         public function get_num_rows() {
            return mysqli_num_rows($this->q_id);
           }
          public function get_row_affected(){
           return mysqli_affected_rows($this->db_connect_id);
          }
             public function get_insert_id() {
           return mysqli_insert_id($this->db_connect_id);
           }
          public  function free_result($q_id) {
            if($q_id == ""){
           $q_id = $this->q_id;
            }
          mysqli_free_result($q_id);
          } 
          public function close_db(){
            return mysqli_close($this->db_connect_id);
          }
         public function more_result() {
          return mysqli_more_results($this->db_connect_id);
          }
         public function next_result() {
           return mysqli_next_result($this->db_connect_id);
             }
           public function __construct(){
            $this->connect();
           }  
           }
            ?>
```

Comment: necesitas una libreria para mostrar pdf fijate en este blog https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/12/23/mostrar-pdf-navegador-php/

Comment: Probé el codigo localmente y no puedo reproducir el problema (pero me pasa lo mismo al entrar en tu pagina), no será que no hayas subido bien el codigo al servidor?. También ten cuidado con las [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/166122), tu código es vulnerable.

Comment: Para los que gusten checar mi problema pueden entrar a la página contago.com.mx y el usuario con la contraseña son prueba

Comment: Puedes poner lo que hay en "c.php"? Obviamente, remplaza con asteriscos todos los datos sensibles. Puede que este ahi el problema.

Comment: Ya amigo he editado mi pregunta agregando el código que hay en c.php

Comment: sale que el `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` valida que no estes cargando otra cosa!

Comment: Disculpa amigo en que momento te sale eso?

Comment: en el header cuando cargas el documento  http://contago.com.mx/larchivos.php?id=76 pero si intentas con el 1 sale  http://contago.com.mx/larchivos.php?id=1. los echo de los header por lo que me dice que tienes un echo en algun lado!

Comment: Mmm bueno el id=76 corresponde al archivo que subiste, pero si intentas con el 1 te marca ese error porque el archivo con ese id no existe